# Using Media Queries in Javascript when opening pop ups

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've using Javascript to open popups on my website, however because of my styling I need to be able to adjust the sizes of the popup based on screen size (in particular max-width 999px and then 1000px+)

My JS to open the pop up is as follows:

```
function openPopUp1() {
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.height = "85%";
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.width = "40%";
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.opacity = '0.1';
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.overflow = 'hidden';
      $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
    }
```

This code works perfectly for any screen width above mobile, but I need the width of the pop up to be 100% instead of 40% for mobile screen in order for it to be functional.

I've tried using the w3 schools tutorial, but to know avail.

```
function myFunction(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        function openPopUp1() {
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.height = "85%";
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.width = "100%";
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.opacity = '0.1';
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.overflow = 'hidden';
      $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
    } 
    } else {
       function openPopUp1() {
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.height = "85%";
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.width = "40%";
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.opacity = '0.1';
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.overflow = 'hidden';
      $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
    } 
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

If someone could point me in the direction of what i'm getting wrong or suggest a more efficient (working!) method it would be much appreciated!

If you need any other resources from me, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function openPopUp1() {
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.height = "85%";
      document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.width = "40%";
      if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) ){
         document.getElementById("Dry2Dry").style.width = "100%";
      }
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.opacity = '0.1';
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.overflow = 'hidden';
      $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
    }
```

it should detect mobile devices and change the width to 100%

Comment: Currently testing purely on my mac with no success when I simulate a mobile device, can I expect this to be working when I test on mobile?
I assume the if statement is recognising my mac as a computer regardless the screensize?

Comment: @MarcusWilliams sorry I should have done `window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight` instead of  `window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight` I updated my anser it should work now